# Can set operatoins be expressed in terms of symmetric difference and set complement?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that the main set operations $A \cap B$, $A \cup B$ and $A \backslash B$ can be expressed in terms of the symmetric difference and the set complement $A \triangle B$ and $A^{c}$.

I'm having no success, since the symmetric difference is associative and commutative and also since $(A \triangle B)^{c} = A^{c} \triangle B$, I figured if there's any way to express $A \cup B$ in terms of it then it must be something of the form $A_{1} \triangle A_{2} \triangle ... \triangle A_{n}$ where each $A_{i}$ is either $A$, $B$, or $A^{c}$ or $B^{c}$. Say we group them so that the $A_{i}$s that have $A$ are together, then we would have something like $A \triangle A \triangle A^{c} \triangle....$ an expression of this form can only ever be equal to $\emptyset, A, A^{c}, U$ where $U$ is the universe. Same goes for the string of $B$s and $B^{c}$s.

Try out any combination of those four possible $A$s and the four possible $B$s and you get none of the set operations mentioned above. For this reason I'm starting to think it might just be impossible, even tho it is listed as an exercise on  [this](https://ciencias.uniandes.edu.co/es/publicaciones/matematica-estructural) book I'm reading.

Comment: Note that because $A \cup B = (A^c \cap B^c)^c$ and $A \setminus B = A \cap B^c$, you can focus on expressing $A \cap B$ because if you can express that, you can do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it, for what is basically a parity argument. I'll write up my rather long-winded version; perhaps someone can simplify it.

Looking at the Venn diagram, it is clear that the only sets you can possibly construct are unions of members of the disjoint partition

$$ (A\cup B)^c, \quad A \backslash B, \quad B \backslash A, \quad A \cap B.$$

Let's encode each possible set as a sequence of 4 bits, with $1 = $ contains that member of the partition, and $0 =$ does not contain that member, written in the order the sets are listed above.  So, e.g. $A = 0101$, and $1111$ represents the whole set. If we let $x_S$ denote the bit string representing a set $S$, then

$$ x_{S^c} = \overline{x_S},$$
i.e. set complement corresponds to bit-wise complement, and
$$x_{A \triangle B} = x_A \oplus x_B,$$
i.e. symmetric difference corresponds to bit-wise `xor`.

**Proposition:** Starting from $A$ and $B$, the only sets you can generate with complement and  symmetric difference have an even number of bits set, i.e. either 0, 2, or 4.

**Proof:** $A$ and $B$ correspond to $0101$ and $0011$ respectively, so those have an even number of bits set. And since there are exactly 4 bits, "complement" takes an even number of bits to an even number of bits. So all we have left to check is `xor`.

Assume $x$ and $y$ have an even number of bits set. Since
$$ 
\begin{align}
x \oplus 0000 &= x\\
x \oplus 1111 &= \bar x\\
\end{align}
$$

we are left with the case where both $x$ and $y$ have $2$ bits set. Then the number of bit positions where both are set is either $0, 1,$ or $2$.

- If it is zero, then there is no overlap, and $x \oplus y = 1111$.
- If it is two, then $x = y$, and $x \oplus y = 0000$.
- If there is exactly one position where both are $1$, then each of $x$ and $y$ have one $1$ bit that isn't matched in the other, which contributes a total of two $1$ bits to the `xor`. And the other set bit in each of $x$ and $y$ is in the same position, so since  $1 \oplus 1 = 0$, this means it doesn't contribute a set bit to the `xor`, making for exactly two set bits in the final `xor`. Q.E.D.

Oh, and since $ x_{A \cap B} = 0001$, you can never generate it.